# Azure DevOps Release Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy a release pipeline from Azure DevOps which would deploy Azure SQL databases.

I get the following error when trying to deploy:

[image]

The database is current sitting behind a private network.

I would appreciate any help. Than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to created a [self-hosted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) agent that lives inside that private network. Once it is installed and configured, it will be available for you to point your pipelines to it